# Unable to reach different network using ubuntu server as a router in gns3

Tags: routing, linux-networking, route, troubleshooting, static-routes

My network is shown in the picture, I am trying to ping from a windows vm to an ubuntu vm in a gns3 network. But I get: "Destination host unreachable".

Network: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xR6S.png

I am trying to use ubuntu server 18.04 as a router.

I've already configured the etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml file in ubuntu server:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s9:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [20.1.0.2/24]
      gateway4: 20.1.0.2
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [20.1.2.1/24]
      gateway4: 20.1.2.1
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [20.1.1.1/24]
      gateway4: 20.1.1.1
```

I've tried adding static routes in ubuntu server using ip add route:

```
sudo ip route add 20.1.0.0/24 via 20.1.0.2
sudo ip route add 20.1.1.0/24 via 20.1.1.1
sudo ip route add 20.1.2.0/24 via 20.1.2.1
```

The output is RTNETLINK answers: File exists but I am not sure if that's the real problem
Also, this is the output of: sudo route -n & ip route

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbb2T.png

Also, I can successfully ping all the Ubuntu Server interfaces from Windows and Ubuntu Desktop. Ex: Windows (20.1.0.1) -> (enp0s8) 20.1.2.1 and Ubuntu (20.1.2.21) -> enp0s9 (20.1.0.2)

Windows's default gateway is 20.1.0.2 (Firewall has been disabled too)

Ubuntu desktop's default gateway is 20.1.2.1

Is it even possible to ping from 20.1.0.1 to 20.1.2.21? or what could be the problem? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I had `RTNETLINK: File exists` I also had problem with network.

Other that that I would also try:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```